# Will Google Analytics Track Dynamic Pages?

Tags: analytics

Here's what I mean.  We've got Google Analytics set up to track all pages visited on the website.  If I direct somebody to "custom-page.html?username=leroyJenkins" will a hit be recorded for that full URL or just for "custom-page.html"?

Thanks!

Comment: Beware that you cannot sent PII data to Google Analytics, like names in this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Google Analytics settings it will be recorded "custom-page.html?username=leroyJenkins". And two URL with different GET-parameters will be shown as two participal pages.
For example, URL's
custom-page.html?username=leroyJenkins and
custom-page.html?username=tomSmith 
would be tracked as two different pages

But if you want to track visits of page custom-page.html independently of GET-parameters, you can exclude them at Administration-> Profile Settings->Exclude URL Query Parameters

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

It will track and report out on the full URL with the query string. So in your case there will be ueserpage.htm?username=bob and userpage.htm?fred, etc. in your GA reports. There are ways to exclude this though. Just go into you profile tab for your site in the GA dashboard note and exclude any query strings you need

Also, you can set up an advanced filter to tell GA to replace what appears in the URI field, with the field name - See more at: http://iqcontent.com/blog/2007/06/dealing-with-query-strings-in-google-analytics/#sthash.5THsnV7D.dpuf